# join command inserts matching fields as new rows, how can a single row per match be generated?

Tags: bash, unix, join

I'm trying to join tables with some shared fields into a single table.

file1 looks like this:

```
organism score_1
orgA 1
orgC 0
```

file2 looks like this:

```
organism score_2
orgA 1
orgD 0
```

and I use the following to join them:

```
join -e 0 -v1 -j 1 --header file1.txt file2.txt > compile.txt
```

but the result is this

```
organism score_1 score_2
orgA 1
orgA 1
orgC 0
orgD 0
```

What I'm trying to get is this

```
organism score_1 score_2
orgA 1 1
orgC 0 0
orgD 0 0
```

Any suggestions for how I could fix this?

Comment: I don't know of any tool that makes this a one-liner. Are you comfortable writing scripts?

Comment: Yes fairly comfortable.

Comment: Then I suggest you write a bash script (or Perl, or whatever you're most adept at), and if you get stuck, update this question.

Comment: @Beta Better `join` options makes this a one-liner...

Comment: @Shawn: Impressive!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to use `-a`, not `-v` (Incidentally, your `join` invocation does not produce the output you said it did):

```
$ join --header -e 0 -a1 -a2 -j1 -o auto file1.txt file2.txt
organism score_1 score_2
orgA 1 1
orgC 0 0
orgD 0 0
```

(Requires the GNU version of join, but since you were already using `--header` I assume that's not a problem)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one in awk:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {                  # hash file1 to hash a
    a[$1]=$2
    next
}
{                          # process file2
    if($1 in a) {          # if $1 in file1 
        print $1,a[$1],$2  # output 
        delete a[$1]       # ... and delete
    } else                 # if not found in file1
        print $1,$2,$2     # output differently
}
END {                      # output the leftovers from file1
    for(i in a)            # order is awk implementation specific
        print i,a[i],a[i]
}' file1 file2
```

Output:

```
organism score_1 score_2
orgA 1 1
orgD 0 0
orgC 0 0
```